# Removing a class from all input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to remove a class from my input elements.I'm using `Data Annotations` in `MVC` and unobtrusive javascript for validation,anyway, when user clicks submit button I want to remove `valid` class from all input elements, because it change all unnecessary input's (non-required) valid (green border color) and it's not looking good.Anyway, I try this:

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function () {
    if ($(".input-validation-error").length == 0) { // if there is no error
        $(this).button('loading');     
    } else {
        $("input").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("valid");
        }); 
    }
```

And it didn't work, also tried:

```
$("input").removeClass("valid");
```

It didn't work either.And I thought maybe it's working before the validation and valid class adding after the click event automatically.So I try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("input").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("valid");
    });
}, 1000);
```

But still no success. I don't know jQuery very well, probably I'm missing something simple.What is the problem?

Comment: if the class is attached to the input element then it should be as simple as `$("input.valid").removeClass('valid')`

Comment: can you check whether the class is added to the input itself or to one of its parent elements

Comment: but all inputs have more than one class.I don't thnik `input.valid `works

Comment: it does.... it check whether the class exists in the classlist

Comment: I checked, it's added all input elements.

Comment: can you alert `alert($('input.valid').length + '-' + $('.valid').length)` before the `if` condition

Comment: then after the `if` condition what is happening? is there a synchronous ajax request or something to save the data

Comment: No there is no ajax request,when I try to submit form if there is an error post request won't send.anyway,interestingly setinterval is working now,it's removing valid classes,the code in the else block doesn't work

Comment: @ArunPJohny  I was wrong,input.valid is working.if you post an answer I will accept it

Comment: but still I don't know why your code is not working.... that also is correct

Comment: @ArunPJohny can I ask you a short question: I write setInterval into document.ready, but it's not working on first opening,if I click submit button,then it's working and removing valid classes in every one second,when I click button page isn't refreshing by the way.I'm just confused why this is happening?

Comment: @ArunPJohny it was working since the beginning but I just noticed, it's working after at least one button click

Comment: are you using the [validator framework](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).... if so you can set the `validClass` property to `''` to avoid adding the class

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes but it's not that framework.My project in asp.net mvc,and I'm using data annotations,I don't know it's using same framework or not.anyway, it was my stupid mistake,I solve the problem.I was write setInterval code into button click event :D instead of document.ready.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r9LDH/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r9LDH/2/

Comment: it is not a good idea to write a setInterval() like that.... it is better to override the css rule like `.valid {
    border: none;
}`

Comment: or try to just add `jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    validClass: ''
})` before the dom ready handler as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r9LDH/2/

Comment: but I'm using that class in another forms.And I don't want to apply this in my other forms.I can't change css

Comment: then add a class to the form like `novalidhightlight` and then add the rule `.novalidhightlight .valid { border: none; }`

Comment: `jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ validClass: '' });`  is working like a charm :) I deleted setInterval.Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the class is attached to the input element then it should be as simple as

```
$("input.valid").removeClass('valid')
```

---

As it turned out OP didn't want the valid highlight to be applied so setting the `validClass` to `''` fixed it

For the page the default validClass was set using

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ validClass: '' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submitBtn").click(function () {
           if ($(".input-validation-error").length == 0) { // if there is no error
                $(this).button('loading');     
           } else {

           $("input").each(function () {
               $(this).removeClass("valid");
           }); 
      }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dwQb4/1/

```
$("input").removeClass("valid");
```

There are 3 inputs with class="valid" that turns them green and some jquery to remove the class

this may help you